Poisson splitting
Still new to posting questions here so please correct any errors.
I have a Poisson arrival process of production orders which can contain a certain number of two types of products A and B.
So a production order contains out of:

N_a={0,1,2....}; N_b={0,1,2...}


with the condition that N_a+N_b>0

I have two machines, one for A and one for B. I split the production orders upon arrival so the arrival of the suborders then also follows a Poisson process, as I split directly on arrival into two suborders sub_a and sub_b:

sub_a={0,1,2....} ; sub_b={0,1,2....}

I also know the probability p_zero,a so that sub_a=0  and p_zero,b for sub_b from a marginal distribution which i have validated using empirical data. The probability p_zero is a combination of a geometrical distribution and a Bernoulli experiment. My question is if the arrival process for the machines still stays Poisson?
My idea was that I can use the thinning property to show that the since the arrival at a machine for example machine A has independent increments. As the arrival of an order containing A and not containing A is independent as we can assume that customer choices of A and B are independent.
My concern is that if an arriving order has no A so sub_a=0, then it must be of type B sub_B>0. So there is a dependency. On the other side I am only interested in the splitting process of suborders at the machines so if we have to produce something in sub_a or not, regardless of sub_b.
Am I making a fundamental mistake here in my thoughts?

Please edit the text to very carefully explain the process and your question. It sounds like you have a Poisson process. Each arrival contains a batch. A single batch include a number of different orders: some number of order type A and some number of order type B. You know the probability of being type A or B. Do you know the distribution for the total number of orders (batch size)? It sounds like your intuition is probably right, that you can split into a type A and type B Poison processes if you knew that distribution. But, as written, it's hard for me to be sure I understand correctly.

Now you have A and B as denoting both sets and numbers (or random variables). Please be very precise with your notation and wording. It takes practice, but it is actually helpful to you solving the problem. I suspect you mean $X_A$ and $X_B$ are the total count of arrivals of the respective types. Thus you are starting with $X_A+X_B$ is a Poisson process, and you are interested in calculating the distinct arrival rates for $X_A$ and $X_B$ individually.

@jdods thank you for the input it is really appreciated.
